# "Glaringly obvious" vs. "blaringly obvious"

Tags: word-choice, etymology, adverbs, eggcorn

I've heard both phrases in everyday speech, so there's little doubt in my mind that the answer is *both*. I suspect, though, that one of these phrases is more the original than the other, and the other sprang out of it from mis-hearing.

*Glaringly obvious* seems essentially redundant; the word *obvious* occurs in the definition of *glaring* in the three dictionaries I looked at.
*Blaringly obvious* is less favored by, say, Google, but actually describes the *obviousness*, as opposed to repeating it.

Are these two statements identical? Is one the forebear of the other?

- It is difficult to resist the urge to fix these glaringly obvious errors.
- It is difficult to resist the urge to fix these blaringly obvious errors.

What about this third? Is it preferable, or does it change the meaning?

- It is difficult to resist the urge to fix these glaring errors.

Comment: @tchrist I wish I had known the word *eggcorn* five minutes ago. Anyway, the question could be phrased, *which is the eggcorn and which the original*, I suppose.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I disagree with your interpretation.

*Glaringly obvious* describes that the thing [metaphorically] glares at you. It's a sight-based metaphor. A similar idiom is *blindingly obvious*.

*Blaringly obvious* is a combination of *glaring* and *blinding*. If something is blaring, it's screaming at you, so while it does have much the same connotations as *glaring* and *blinding*, it's a sound-based metaphor and less suited for seeing what is obvious.

I suspect that the original user misused both *glaringly* and *blindingly* and ended up with what is effectively a Spoonerism. Since then, it's either been used deliberately as an off-beat metaphor (sound-based rather than sight-based) or it's an eggcorn.

Comment: That a thing glares at you is only one definition of *glaring*. Is there documented etymology to suggest that the other definitions of *glaring* stem from this? Also, the word *blaring* [comes from the Middle English *bleren*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blaring), and is not a combination of *glaring* and *blinding*.

Comment: You misunderstand. The word *blaring* is old; but it's used here through the (probably mistaken) combination of "glaring" and "blinding".

Comment: May I suggest that there's another word in play here? --*blatantly*.

Comment: @StoneyB Possibly, but would not a word starting *bl–* and ending *–ingly* be more likely?

Comment: Oh, indeed. I'm not suggesting *blatantly* **instead of** but **alongside** *blaringly*.

Comment: And yet *blatant* is just another word that has *obvious* in its definition – not that that rules anything out, but it makes me sad for the creativity of the human race.

Comment: @kojiro You might want to ask a question about tautology in adjectives like that. It's a different question from asking about "blaringly" here. [Note: I have no idea how to phrase such a question, but it could be valid.]

Comment: I agree conflation of the standard forms *glaringly/blindingly* is probably responsible for OP's "non-standard" form. Primarily through ignorance rather than "not-so-witty wordplay", I feel.

Answer (score 6):

They're not identical because "to blare" is sound-related and "to glare" is light/sight-related.

The standard idiom is *glaringly obvious*, like a fluorescent pink tie.

The *blaringly obvious* variant is used by some, but probably the people who also say *I would of* instead of the correct *I would have*.

I'd say that *glaringly obvious* came first.

Comment: Evidence, or just a general sense?

Comment: Google Books ngrams show no uses of "blaringly obvious" for the past 200 years; Google search changes the terms "blaringly obvious" to "glaringly obvious"; in 69 years of reading, writing, speaking, listening, teaching, & editing English, I've never encountered "blaringly obvious" but have frequently encountered "glaringly obvious". I know that the current younger generations of native speakers of English are fairly illiterate despite their plethora of consumer educational credentials, & that illiteracy was worse in days of yore, but the good writers said "glaringly obvious". 本当に

Comment: If you're going to make value judgements about it, then why don't we drop all the two-word phrases and just go for pithy alternatives like *obvious* and *blatant*? :)

Comment: I think that _glaring errors_ and _glaringly obvious errors_ aren't different in denotative meaning, but when people tell me that what's obvious is obvious, I generally feel patronized. So I'd say that the connotation of the second phrase is that the person being spoken to missed the errors, but that the connotation of the first is that both speaker and listener are equally aware of the errors and of each other's awareness of the errors. Modifying the word _errors_, which needs no emotional support, is always a value judgment. Human nature.

Comment: @kojiro: "If you're going to make value judgements about it, then why don't we drop all the two-word phrases..." Point of order: we're only making value judgements because you asked the question :^)

Comment: +1 for the robust defence in your comment that this answer doesn't really need to cite evidence. I'm not sure how to classify [blatantly obvious](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blatantly+obvious&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) though - acceptable emphatic form, or ignorant tautology?

Comment: @J.R. I'm not really averse to the value judgement, but to be fair the question is not *which is better?*, but *which came first?*

Comment: Are they saying "would of" or "would've"? While it may be a generally unaccepted contraction for print, "would've" is very common in speech (as are others). That inherently means the distinction is much harder to make, but I personally _say_ "would've" and would _never_ confuse it with "would of".

Answer (score 2):

Since no one has cited evidence of the relative frequency of the two phrases, I offer this Ngram chart comparing instances of "glaringly obvious" (blue line) to instances of "blaringly obvious" (red line) for the period 1800–2005:

[image]

As you may be able to detect from this chart "blaringly obvious" has managed to pull itself very slightly off the floor (relative to "glaringly obvious") only in the very recent past.

The two earliest matches for "blaringly obvious" that a Google Books search finds are from 1972 and 1973. From an [unidentified article](https://books.google.com/books?id=xi0dAQAAMAAJ&q=%22blaringly+obvious%22&dq=%22blaringly+obvious%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjT06i3u9ToAhV6ITQIHc2fAoMQ6AEwAnoECAEQAg) in *Commonweal*, volume 97 (1972) [combined snippets]:

> This was perhaps too subtle to be noticed; not as subtle as Henry James, but nonetheless not as **blaringly obvious** as the more bizarre elements of the novel. If Father Schroth missed it, the reason might be that he was looking for less in the novel than was actually there.

And from an [unidentified essay](https://books.google.com/books?id=4L4PAAAAMAAJ&q=%22blaringly+obvious%22&dq=%22blaringly+obvious%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjS64aavNToAhXBFjQIHZhhC34Q6AEwAHoECAAQAg) in *Husbanding the Golden Grain: Studies in Honor of Henry W. Nordmeyer* (1973):

> This may explain partly why there were at best only a handful of singers who sang well in such an intense and frustrating mode of expression, and why their singing was, relatively, short-lived. After Morungen and Reinmar the art had to change. The change was audible in the songs of Walther and **blaringly obvious** in those of Neidhart.

The argument for "blaringly" over "glaringly" in the 1973 essay is that the context is sound (music), which does tend to blare rather than glare when it goes wrong. The context in the 1972 article however, is literature, and the printed page is normally accused of blaring only when the font used is large and loud.

Although one must assume that the words that appear in print are intentional, I note that the <kbd>G</kbd> key on a keyboard is adjacent to the <kbd>B</kbd> key, and it would not take a great slip to wind up on the wrong key. Still, it is clear that a number of people in speech and a smaller number in writing now endorse "blaringly obvious." The number even seems to be growing (very slightly) relative to the number of "glaringly obvious" users. But until Ngram or other gauges of usage show distinct separation between the relative level of usage of "blaringly obvious" and a flatline, many hearers and readers are likely to interpret the expression as a malapropism.

Comment: If you invoke Google ngram with 'blaringly', (no 'obvious') you will get an increasing response of this word since the 19th century, sharply accelerating in usage since 2000. The word also is in dictionaries, which confirms that it is a legitimate word, and has been for some time. It's an adjective with a clear definition. However, using it together with 'obvious' is utter nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to propose something slightly different. I think we all recognize that there is a series of words, *glare, glaring, glaringly*. However the parallel series of words, *blare, blaring, blaringly* results in a word that is not generally accepted as a word and is the word in question - blaringly.

The two previous answers, which both point out the visual nature of glare and audible nature of blare, are useful for that particular reason. However I don't think "it's glaring at you" is the right definiens to choose for this particular application, but glaring in the sense that it is reflecting (focused) bright light. With this interpretation *glaringly* would be the adverb of choice for visual events while *blaringly* would be the adverb of choice for audible events. I feel that both these words, *glaring* and *blaring,* have an inability-to-ignore connotation, but that is tangential.

For comparison, I put forth the words *oblige* and *obligation*; the former is a verb and the latter is a noun, both of which English received from Old French or Latin directly (approx. 13th century). In the course of verbifying the noun we received the word *obligate* (and it's relatives, such as *obligated*) which are now common words. My understanding is that the -ation suffix comes in its entirety through the Latin and French streams, and is applied, in its entirety, to the word *oblige*, resulting in *obligation.* To reverse this properly, one would return to *oblige,* but it appears that is has instead been shortened only partially to *obligate.* Thus, English now has the words *obligate* from the 16th or 17th century when in occurs in no other language, probably from this "back-conjugation" procedure.

That's all to say, what I'm suggesting is just a conjugation of blare or blaring to blaringly that conforms to other similar English conjugations, and would be construed as the natural development of language over time.

Part of the original question was whether to use "glaringly obvious" or "glaring." In the exact examples offered, I don't think there is a difference, but still have the following opinion: If the same choice was offered 7 times in a paragraph, I would, as a rule, choose the latter as choosing the former for all 7 would create an excessively wordy paragraph that didn't increase content in any way. That said, however, *glaring* is an adjective while *glaringly* is an adverb; this implies that at some point where the verb is not redundant to the adverb that *glaringly* will be preferred. For example, something could be *glaringly obnoxious* which implies that it is both vile and obviously so, which is not as redundant as being obviously obvious.